# Interoperational Dangerous?

Tags: security, network

Can interoperational Chains like Cosmos be dangerous for the Tezos Network itself?

Do such Chains "act" on our Tezos network? Or is it a complete own Space?
Could such interoperational functions open doors for vulnerabilities?

Just read this article, what leads me to the question(s):
https://medium.com/certus-one/uncovering-a-game-of-stakes-cartel-f895d9591da1

Comment: In your article the cost of getting one more stake is 0 aside from the effort to bypass KYC, so is this really concerning ? This is just a tesnet no ? And pardon my ignorance but could you please clarify the link between the article you posted and cosmos and how all this can impact Tezos ? It is not clear to me after having read the entire article.

Comment: The link should show, that a network that is somehow "connected" to ours got tricked. And i am concernd that this could have influence to the Tezos Network. That's what i wanted to know. Is Tezos somehow affected by any interoperational Chains.